# How To Backup Encryption Certificate To S3 From An Amazon RDS SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I need to make a backup of a SQL Server database encryption certificate where SQL Server is installed on Amazon RDS.

Just for testing purposes, I've temporarily created a public S3 bucket called 'mypublicbucket' - it has no read or write restrictions.

Here is my command (for testing purposes) that I'm running from the database where the certificate exists:

```
BACKUP CERTIFICATE My_Certificate TO FILE = 'arn:aws:s3:::mypublicbucket/MyCertificate.cer';
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot write into file 'arn:aws:s3::: mypublicbucket/MyCertificate.cer'. Verify that you have write permissions, that the file path is valid, and that the file does not already exist.
```

For an extra bit of information, from the master database of this same installation, I'm able to successfully run `execute exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database`, where the backup file is written to an s3 bucket.

Any thoughts would be appreciated on how to address this error.

Comment: You should be asking AWS support how to do this. For RDS instances AWS supply their own msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database to backup databases to S3 and msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database to restore databases from S3. You'll need to find out if they supply equivalent procedures to backup and restore certificates.

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that you're not talking about the default RDS Encryption option (which uses EBS Volume encryption), but instead a certificate that you have specifically configured within your DB. If so I would recommend performing a backup of the whole database to S3 and restoring to another RDS instance and confirming that the certificate has been backed-up as part of a normal DB backup. (i.e. you may not need to backup the cert specifically, but just the DB as a whole)